# Navigation Drawer: change selected item after replace another fragment

Tags: android-studio

I'm using android default navigation drawer activity. Assume i have fragment A and fragment B, there is one button in fragment A and it will redirect(replace) from fragment A to B after the button is clicked.
But the selected item in navigation drawer is still highlighting fragment A. Is there any method to change it to highlight the fragment B instead of A?

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

```
    if(carplate.getText().toString().equals("")){Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter your car plate number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else{
    Status status = new Status();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,status);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

this function is under fragment A. [I need the selected item automatic change to fragment B(Status) after i pressed the button in fragment A.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvkUs.jpg)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Edited. Is that ok? or u need other specified code?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is very easy 
first, you have to get Navigation View and then get the menu from that navigation view and high light/show selection on the basis of the item index which is start from the 0. Place the following line of code in the onclick method.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

and if you want to open the fragment use the following lines of code with the stated code lines

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.mainFragment,new yourNewFragment()).commit()
```

I hope this is helping